# Xcode 6 iOS 8 Rotation Issue - Large Blank Space On Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, rotation

I am running into a very strange issue with my iPad app in Xcode 6. Previously (When building with Xcode 5 / iOS 7 SDK) it would handle rotations with no problem, but now that developers are required to build with Xcode 6 / iOS 8 SDK, my app no longer handles rotation properly.

I did some research and was able to use the viewWillTransitionToSize method in order to get all my subviews to properly rotate and resize themselves. However, my screen has a large white rectangle along the side when I rotate. If I start the app in portrait and rotate to landscape, it goes from looking normal to having a large white space on the right.
(The same thing happens if I start in landscape and rotate to portrait, but the white space is on the bottom).

My subviews are definitely resizing themselves properly, but that white space unfortunately covers them up. I checked the both the bounds and frame of my UIScreen window and those values seem valid (1024w x 768h in landscape, 768w x 1024h in portrait). Previously it was a black space but once I added the line `[self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` to my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, it became a white space.
The following is the viewWillTransitionToSize code that I'm using:

```
- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size WithTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    UIInterfaceOrientation *orientation = [self interfaceFromTransform:[coordinator targetTransform]];
    UIInterfaceOrientation *oldOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:1.0];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> content)
    {
        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:1.0];
    }
    completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        [self didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:oldOrientation];
    }];

    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width)];
}
```

interfaceFromTransform is a method I created to determine which interface the transform is rotating to:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceFromTransform: (CGAffineTransform)transform
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation old = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    int rotation = 0;

    if (transform.b == -1 && transform.c == 1)
        rotation = 90;
    if (transform.b == 1 && transform.c == -1)
        rotation = -90;
    if (transform.a == -1 && transform.d == -1)
        rotation = 180;

    if (old == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        if (rotation == 90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        if (rotation == -90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
        if (rotation == 180)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
    if (old == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        if (rotation == 90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
        if (rotation == -90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        if (rotation == 180)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    if (old == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        if (rotation == 90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        if (rotation == -90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        if (rotation == 180)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
    if (old == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        if (rotation == 90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        if (rotation == -90)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        if (rotation == 180)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }

    return old;
}
```

Yet despite all this, that white space still refuses to go away. Is there something obvious that I'm missing that will keep it from appearing when I rotate the screen?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout and Autoconstraints ?

Comment: @Avis I am not, no. I tried using Autolayout and Autoconstraints but it did not appear to change anything.

Comment: @Avis After some experimenting I was able to solve the issue. As it turns out, I had disabled "Autoresize Subviews" in my main window nib file. Enabling this option worked like a charm. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had disabled "Autoresize Subviews" in my main window nib file. Enabling this immediately fixed the problem.